# how to pass id in api

Tags: angular

I have problem in sending id from front to backend.

this.http.get('${this.api/getOrder}/${orderId}') but it is giving garbage value.

```
this.http.get('/api/getOrder?orderId=${orderId}')
```

I expect this orderId in api to update the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the backTicks:

```
this.http.get(`/api/getOrder?orderId=${orderId}`)
```

[image: Image showing backticks]

> **[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** are string literals allowing embedded expressions.
>
> These are enclosed by the back-tick (``` `` ```).Template literals can
>   contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly
>   braces (${expression}). The expressions in the placeholders and the
>   text between the back-ticks () get passed to a function. The
>   default function just concatenates the parts into a single string. You
>   can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with
>   them.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
this.http.get('/api/getOrder?orderId=${orderId}')
```

with

```
this.http.get(`/api/getOrder?orderId=${orderId}`)
```

you should use **backtick** instead of **single quotation** if you have an expression inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to send parameters in get request:

Before ES6

> this.http.get("/api/getOrder?orderId="+orderId)

After ES6, this can also be used:

> this.http.get(`/api/getOrder?orderId=${orderId}`)